# How to use ag-grid Export to excel functionality with large data(50,000 rows) with Angular 6 (OUT OF MEMORY error)?

Tags: angular, angular6, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am currently working with export to excel functionality in ag-grid with angular 6 with large data 50,000 rows?

When I have less data 1000 records, I am able to download the file easily (<1 second) but as I have increased the data to 50000 rows , My web browser becomes unresponsive and I get the chrome error "Something went wrong" after a while. My code is

---

```
onBtExport() {
var params = {
    suppressTextAsCDATA: true,
    allColumns:true,
    onlySelected: false,
    fileName:this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#fileName').value,
    sheetName: 
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#sheetName').value
};
//this.gridApi.exportDataAsExcel(params);
var content = this.gridApi.getDataAsExcel(params);
var workbook = XLSX.read(content, {type: 'binary'});
var xlsxContent = XLSX.write(workbook, {bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'base64'});
download(params, xlsxContent);
}
```

With grid data about 1000 rows , This is working absolutely fine ,I am able to download the file in my browser in about 1 second , but as I increase by data to 50000 rows , My browser becomes unresponsive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data in AG-Grid is stored in memory if the size exceeds chrome will throw Out Of Memory error.
I had a similar issue while exporting 50,000 plus data thru Ag-Grid would crash browser for few users.
Below are few things which can be considered

1. Rather than using a grid API method create a server side method to export large data
2. CSV export is faster than Excel Export, but you will not get formatting
3. Try below code which i am using but its not 100% full proof but helps notifying user that some action happening in background

   ```
    $scope.onBtExportXls = function () {$scope.agGridOptions.api.showLoadingOverlay();

   setTimeout(function () {

   content = this.gridOptions.api.getDataAsExcel(xlsExcelParams);

   var blobObject = new Blob(["\ufeff", content], {
           type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8;"
       });

   if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
       window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, fileName);
   }
   else {
       // Chrome
       var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
       downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobObject);
       downloadLink.download = fileName;
       document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
       downloadLink.click();
       document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
   }      
   $scope.agGridOptions.api.hideOverlay();
   }, 50);};
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the line  `content = this.gridOptions.api.getDataAsExcel(xlsExcelParams);`  is itself resulting in an out of memory error.

Comment: Can you please tell me that if we download the excel file from server side then how to implement this if we are setting some filters on ag-grid.

Comment: Yes this can be achieved by using Grid API method `gridOptions.api.getFilterModel()`.
This will return an object with what field filter was applied, what is the type of filter (set, date, number) and the values passed to the filter.
Use this model and filter accordingly using LINQ or in SQL on the server side.
Hope this will help. [Plunker Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/r7D63CH7GVuAqJqoTIST?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks very much ,in the latest ag grid version 20.1.0 release notes , the developers have said that they have fixed the out of memory error with large data, so did you try using that. if that worked I will also update my ag grid version.

Comment: @Yatharth Mishra, sure i need to try upgrading we are still using 17.0. Will let you know if its working or not after upgrade. Thanks for marking as correct answer.

Comment: Can you please tell if I am sorting a column apart from applying filters on it ,then how to fetch that information,

Comment: Similar to getFilterModel there is api to get sorting model `gridOptions.api.getSortModel()`. 
This will return an array of model `{colId: "country", sort: "asc"}`. 
The same can be used on the server side to apply order by. I understand it is not straight forward and you will have to code to achieve your expectation. 
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/upOm7otK4LEX6d6iYZRV?p=preview)
Do give a vote up if helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have several choices to fix this issue:
1) download as many rows as possible then download second part, third... and so on
you can do this by exportDataAsExcel(params) where params are implements BaseExportParams
 which has several fields for example you can use onlySelected.
2) More convenient way to do this is create backend service without using ag-grid api.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if I use a backend service for creating and downloading the excel file , then how to implement if I am setting some filters on ag grid.